# MySQL combining datas from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
TABLE surveys:

id   survey_title       date           active
1    Example Survey     1508842162     1
2    Example Survey2    1508842162     1


TABLE survey_user_relation:

id    user_id       survey_id(foregin_key)       active
1     1             1                            1
2     1             2                            0
3     2             1                            1
```

I have two table as above. column active represents if a survey is closed from all the users in survey table and closed from just one user in survey_user_relation table. user_id and survey_id are set to UNIQUE key together so that one user can be related to the same survey only once. 
I am trying to list all the surveys and I want to know if a user is related with that survey in one query if possible.

I tried

```
SELECT * 
  FROM surveys s
  LEFT 
  JOIN survey_user_relation u
    ON u.survey_id = s.id 
 WHERE u.user_id = 2
```

But it only gives one survey I need to see all the surveys and know if the user is related.

Thanks in advance

Edit:

I need to see something like

```
id   survey_title       date           active     user_id
1    Example Survey     1508842162     1          2
2    Example Survey2    1508842162     1          NULL
```

Comment: remove `WHERE user_id = 2`. This is causing you to show defined result for mentioned user id.

Comment: then it duplicates the surveys

Comment: What does "duplicates the surveys" mean. You are not clear. Use enough words.

Comment: Change `WHERE` to `AND` -- and only select the columns you actually want returned.

Comment: @philipxy
it means it returns the same survey more than once since the same survey is related twice

Comment: If you're still struggling, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: "the same survey is related twice" is also vague. There are some tables with columns & rows & PKs & FKs, use enough words & the right words to say what you mean. Giving an example is good. "Something like is also vague. Give some input & say what its expected output is. Say what you mean. For the future please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
SELECT s.*, u.* 
    FROM surveys s
    LEFT JOIN survey_user_relation u
    ON u.survey_id = s.id AND u.user_id = 2;
```

With where he is only getting entries which really have user_id = 2. On a left join he checks if one is there otherwise it returns null for the columns.
By the way you dont need the row ID on your second table. Just set survey_id and user_id to primary.

Comment: This returns only survey 1 which is okay but i need to see survey 2 too

Comment: I need to see null columns too to know if the user is related with the survey

Answer (score 0):

I think you're interested in this result:

```
SEELCT distinct s.survey_title, u.user_id
FROM surveys AS S LEFT JOIN survey_user_relation AS U 
ON U.survey_id = S.id
```